# Swift - Use of unresolved identifier error after update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I updated my OS to El Capitan and at the same time I guess XCode got updated (Now 7.2), prior to this when I would run my code in the simulator it worked fine. Now When I try to run the code for a calendar in my first view controller in a tabbed application it gives me the error "use of unresolved identifier 'SACalendar'" however everything else seems to be okay. I'm not sure if there was any syntax changes or something with the update, but it seems to be a common issue so I tried to review some other postings but was unable to find anything pertaining to my issue. Does anyone know whats going on? There error is in the code below, and SACalendar is a .m file that is included via bridging header. The bridging header **does** include all the necessary .h files, including the SACalendar.h

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SACalendarDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        /*
        * Smooth scrolling in vertical direction
        * - to change to horizontal, change the scrollDirection to ScrollDirectionHorizontal
        * - to use paging scrolling, change pagingEnabled to true
        * - the calendar works with any size
        */

        //Get the width and the height of the device
        let frameWidth = self.view!.frame.size.width
        let frameHeight = self.view!.frame.size.height - 110

        var calendar : SACalendar = SACalendar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 80, frameWidth, frameHeight), scrollDirection: ScrollDirectionVertical, pagingEnabled: true)
        //error occurs due to the SACalendar on the righthand side of assignment operator
        calendar.delegate = self
        self.view!.addSubview(calendar)

    }
}
```

The bridging header:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#ifndef YogaAdmin_Bridging_Header_h
#define YogaAdmin_Bridging_Header_h

#import "DateUtil.h"
#import "DMLazyScrollView.h"
#import "SACalendar.h"
#import "SACalendarCell.h"
#import "SACalendarConstants.h"

#endif
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `import SACalendar` at the top of this file?

Comment: @BHendricks Yes it then says no such module because it's being included through a bridging header so I don't think the import is needed

Comment: and it's not complaining about `SACalendarDelegate`?

Comment: No complaints there, and it also does not complain about the use of the first SACalendar on the left hand side of assignment operator

Comment: can you post bridging header as well?

Comment: @VivekMolkar yes of course, I just updated.

Comment: Yup a strange issue though, was able to reproduce too, will update if I find the breakthrough.

Comment: @cwattsdis A Dirty trick I tried – Renamed `SACalendar` to `SACalendar1` and the Error vanished. Looking into what is causing this.

Comment: Hm, weird. The error still occurs for me even when doing that

Comment: Of course you have refreshed the *DerivedData*?

Comment: Hi Guys, Is there any solution for same issues?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and I was finding that delegate functions names same as class name which was creating issues in swift so i was solved it by change Delegate functions name.

```
-(void) SACalendar:(SACalendar*)calendar didDisplayCalendarForMonth:(int)month year:(int)year;
-(void) SACalendar:(SACalendar*)calendar didSelectDate:(int)day month:(int)month year:(int)year;

 TO

-(void) Calendar:(SACalendar*)calendar didDisplayCalendarForMonth:(int)month year:(int)year;
-(void) Calendar:(SACalendar*)calendar didSelectDate:(int)day month:(int)month year:(int)year;
```

And Replaced SACalendar to Calendar where delegate functions are called.

Thanks